# Querying returning no rows in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to run this SQL Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tickets_extra_emails`
WHERE ticketnumber = '50909'
    AND email_address = 'testing@domain.com'
```

But its saying no rows returned however when i browse the table there are multiple rows with the above values

Comment: If the query returns zero rows then there are zero rows that match.  Perhaps there is some whitespace somewhere throwing things off.  If possible, try to create a script that will populate the table with dummy data and post that script here, showing the query that fails to return rows against that dummy data.

Comment: What is the data type of the `ticketnumber` field? Is that really a character type and not a number?

Comment: ticketnumber = varchar(20)

Comment: there is defiantly a row that matches this - how can i tell if there is any white space?

Comment: Do you get results if you remove one of the conditions?

Comment: remove the quotes in ``tickets_extra_emails`` and add a `;` at the end of your sql statement (if you didn't)

Comment: if you change email_address = 'testing@domain.com' to email_address LIKE '%testing@domain%' do you get anything? I know that will grab everything with testing@domain in it, but just to see

Comment: @ItalianStallion yes it works if i use the %% and letsjack if i use ONLY where ticketnumber... OR where email_address... it works fine. it just doesnt work when i use both

Comment: @user3843997 Then the answer is that there is no ticket row with *both* that ticket number and that email address.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is correct, no result means that you have no row that contains exactly these values. Be careful when working with `VARCHAR` values because spaces placed at the beginning of your value will make your result unequal (the spaces at the end will not affect the equal operation but in case of a `LIKE` clause both beginning and ending spaces will be taken into account)!

Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM `tickets_extra_emails` T
WHERE TRIM(T.ticketnumber) = '50909'
    AND TRIM(T.email_address) = 'testing@domain.com'
```

The only difference with your version of the query is the use of `TRIM()` function. This function will remove every spaces placed at the beginning/end of your values and it may solve your problem.

In you're still having no result, provide us a sample of data because your problem is for sure the values you've in your table and not the query you're using here.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Trailing spaces at the end of varchar values [are not considered during equality tests](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/bcf622/2), but they *are* considered during `LIKE` tests.  Just wanted to clarify this point since you claim that spaces placed at the end will also cause problems; only spaces at the beginning would.

Comment: @cdhowie Thank you for this clarification, i've completed my answer to include your feedback